# Is there a good way to join these two objects up?

Tags: edges

Blender Newb here. So take with a grain of salt. : )

I'm learning blender for my job so I'm trying to 3d out some of our past work. I've got this monument sign I'm trying to do to teach myself.

In the picture I've got you can see there is the horizontal curved blue object and the vertically curved purple. I'm trying to get these two curved object to meet at the yellow line to form a doubly curved edge.

Is there anyway to do this without haven't to piece the vertices together one by one?

Let me know if you need more info.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post .blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I could elaborate more on this topic.

Comment: You want to totally close the shape along the line ?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to get the outward edges of the blue and purple to come together at the line.

Comment: As @LukeD said this is hard to give a solution if we do not know how blue and purple meshes are inside. You should upload your file at the link he indicated. But anyway, if blue and purple inner geometry are not homogeneous (same amount of vertices, more or less), the answer won't be self evident. If they are not, please indicate if this matters or not.

Comment: Okay. I'll upload it when I get back to the office.

Comment: The .blend should be posted.

Comment: Did you create those objects in Blender or import them?

Comment: I created everything in Blender. No external program was used on anything.

Comment: I don't really know where to start. Do you have any reference image with final result?

Comment: I have posted the reference image I have been using.

Comment: With your mesh this connection isn't possible (theoretically is but practically not). Do you want me to make answer with completly different method to model this element?

Comment: That would be helpful yes. Thank you. Like I said I've still got the fresh Blender smell and tried piecing this all together over a couple of days.

Comment: Could you find my website in my profile and conntact me trough email? We could discuss details before I post answer.

Comment: I've made answer (second one) but still if you want to know more about whole modeling process and material assign reach me trough mail, because this isn't related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches I might use.

Boolean modifier is the most straight forward route - make the blue and purple parts larger so they overlap, and then use the intersection operation. A route like this usually works well in CAD software, but it's often not the best in Blender.

A better approach in Blender is using its mesh editing tools like proportional editing (the <kbd>o</kbd> key in edit mode).

- Start with a plane, rotate it to face the front and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter edit mode.
- Use <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to sale in one axis and <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to scale in the other, and <kbd>G</kbd> to position it into the right space.
- Subdivide it using loop cut, to get a bunch of edges along where it needs to curved (use the scroll where to increase the number of cuts):
  [image: split plane]
- Select the one or two vertices in the top middle (using `RMB` and `SHIFT+RMB` if selecting two). Press <kbd>o</kbd> to use proportional editing mode. Press <kbd>g</kbd> to start moving the vertices. Press <kbd>z</kbd> to only move on the Z axis. Use the scroll wheel to increase the size of the white circle so you start moving all the vertices at once. You can try <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to cycle different fall offs ("Inverse Square" worked best for me):
  [image: PET]
  The bottom is also curved. We'll fix that later.
- Now do the same for the other axis from the top view (press <kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad), but this time select both the top vertices and bottom vertices. Again, use <kbd>g</kbd> to grab, and now <kbd>y</kbd> to constrain to the Y axis.
- Let's fix the bottom edge. Turn proportional editing off using <kbd>o</kbd>. Switch back to front view using <kbd>1</kbd> on numpad. Select the whole bottom row by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and clicking and edge (or <kbd>B</kbd> and drawing a box around it). Press <kbd>S</kbd> to start scaling, <kbd>z</kbd> to constrain to the Z axis, and <kbd>`0`</kbd> to scale to zero.
- The whole thing may need its position fixed now. <kbd>a</kbd> to select all and use the on screen widget to move it around one axis at a time

To finish it, and add the ridge at the top, you can use extrusions:

- Select the top row using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> followed by <kbd>y</kbd> and drag the mouse to extrude outward along the Y axis
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> followed by <kbd>z</kbd> and drag to extrude upward along the Z axis
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> again to extrude it inward

Answer (score 1):

[image: Final]

### Reference setup:

First of all setup your reference image by adding it to your viewport and setting it to te center of the grid as shown in the picture below.

Check *Background Images* then *Add image*, select *Axis*, open reference image and finally setup *H* and *V* values.

Do this for *Front Ortho* (<kbd>1</kbd> on numpad) and *Top Ortho* (<kbd>7</kbd> on numpad) view. <kbd>5</kbd> on numapad to switch between *Ortho/Perspective view*.

[image: Setup]

### Creating a mesh:

Create *Cube*.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Cube*.

Position it as shown in picture below.

- <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> for *Front View*.
- <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> for *Top View*.

[image: Position]

### Modeling mesh:

**Front view.**

1. Go to *Edit mode* - <kbd>Tab</kbd> - and press <kbd>Z</kbd> for wire view in both viewports.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to make a *Loop Cut*, position your cursor over cube to get verticall cut and <kbd>Left click</kbd> on it then <kbd>Right click</kbd>. Deselect all by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>B</kbd> for *Area Select*, select right side of our mesh, hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*

[image: Steps 2]

3. Now using method above (deselect all by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>B</kbd>) select vertices and move them accordingly to the picture. It's important to select them by *Area select* because we want to select both side of the mesh.

[image: Step 3]

4. It's time to add more *Loop Cuts* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and position it using the same method as above. Remember to move them only on *Z Axis* - <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> or drag *Z Axis* (blue arrow) with <kbd>Left mouse button</kbd>.

[image: Step 4]

**Top view:**

5. In *Top view* do the same to match curve from reference. This time move vertices along *Y Axis*.

[image: Step 5]

### Final touches:

1. Go to *Object Mode* <kbd>Tab</kbd>, press <kbd>Z</kbd> for *Solid View* and add *Mirror Modifier*.

[image: F Step 1]

2. Set *Shading* to *Smooth* and turn on *Autosmooth*.

[image: F Step 2]

### What else?

Now you can add the rest of elements or extrude them from this base mesh. I've made some of examples in different layers in this blend file:

[image]

**First layer** - simple mesh with *Autosmooth*.

[image: First layer]

**Second layer** - *Autosmooth* with *Mean Crease* and *SubSurf*.

[image: Second layer]

**Third layer** - *Mean Crease*, *SubSurf* with *Loop Cuts*.

[image: Third layer]